# Continuous evaluation of engine in ChessBase

Tags: engines, evaluation, chessbase

I just bought ChessBase 13 and downloaded Stockfish, but when I am analyzing my games there is no continuous evaluation of the moves. So say I make 3 extra moves, the engine is still calculating the position 3 moves before. How can I change so that the engine automatically calculates the position on the board, so that it will go along with the moves?

Hope you can help!!

Answer (score 1):

I bet you turned on the "Lock engine" toggle, which tells the engine to keep analyzing the position it's on even when the board changes. There's a padlock icon in the engine window. Try clicking it so the padlock is open.